# WiX installer: Log message in CustomAction run by DoAction

Tags: c#, logging, wix, windows-installer, custom-action

I am writing a WiX installer with some custom action.
I read [here](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Why-doesn-t-logging-from-an-immediate-custom-action-work-td709678.html) that `Session.Log` in a C# Custom Action doesn't work if the action is run as a result of a button click (DoAction).
MSDN says that [you can use the Message Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368322(v=vs.85).aspx), so I tried with Session.Message:

```
var foo = new Record(1);
foo.SetString(0, "hello world");
session.Message(InstallMessage.ActionData, foo);
```

but I still can't see the log message even when using VERBOSE=1.
The installer is created with WiX Burn so there isn't a separated msi.

Any help please?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, this is a known issue with the underlying Windows Installer:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368322(v=vs.85).aspx

It seems that after Server 2003 the Message method may work but honestly I stopped using script custom actions years ago so it's not an option for me.  I use C#/DTF which uses MsiProcessMessage.

The usual workaround for this is to take advantage of the fact that property changes get logged.  Just set an unused property a bunch of times and you have your data in the log.

Comment: That's the link I was quoting. could you expand " I use C#/DTF which uses MsiProcessMessage." please?

Comment: DTF is a feature of WiX that allows you to write managed custom actions.  see: http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2008/05/deployment-tools-foundation-dtf-custom.html

Comment: The source to the Session class is here: https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/DTF/Libraries/WindowsInstaller/Session.cs   You can see on line 210 that they use MsiProcessMessage()

Comment: RemotableNativeMethods can be found here: https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/DTF/Libraries/WindowsInstaller/RemotableNativeMethods.cs

Comment: PS:  This is why I stopped using script custom actions years ago: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robmen/2004/05/20/vbscript-and-jscript-msi-customactions-suck/

Comment: Despite the MSDN docs, I think all paths lead to MsiProcessMessage.

Comment: @PhilDW That's very, very plausible.

Comment: PS- I first read this very quickly and it looked like Script to me. I now realize that it's C#/DTF code and yes MsiProcessMessage would be the path.  This won't work.  Just do the set property trick as a work around.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter yes I was using `Session.Log` and wasn't working.

Comment: This is a known issue with Windows Installer.  Please accept my answer.